# Align login form table to top-middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, alignment

I have button value Show Login Page with `onclick` funtion to popup login screen. I did the click function correctly but I want that form to show at the top middle of the screen. I tried but it's aligning at the left middle only.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
    <body>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="pop.js"></script>
    <input type="button" value="Show Login Page" onclick="showLogin();">
<form style="visibility:hidden" name="loginform" method="post" action="#">
<br><br>
<table align="top"><tr><td><h2>Login Authentication</h2></td></tr></table>
<table align="top" style="border:1px solid #000000;background-color:#efefef; height: 78px;">
<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>Login Name</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>Password</b></td>
  <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pop.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLogin() {
        document.loginform.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
</script>
```

Screenshot actual:

[image]

Screenshot expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set left margin for **loginform** like below :

```
#loginform{
   margin-left:50%;
}
```

Give id to form as loginform like below:

```
<form  name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action="#">
```

**OR**

You can also use following css:

```
#loginform
{
   position:fixed;
    left:40%;

}
```

[Here is JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tkvvkj1/)

[Here is Full Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3tkvvkj1/1/)

**Update as per Comment:**

Please Check out updated Code- [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3tkvvkj1/2/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. It's coming at the top-middle but not exactly at the top. Is it possible to get it like this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vz1m.png

Comment: Add css property top:0px;

Comment: Also do not forget to remove <br> tag from your code.